# Spring MVC RequestMapping is being forwarded

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a REST service based on Spring MVC.

This is my code:

```
public class SitesController {

@RequestMapping(value="/rest/sites/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public SiteDTO getSite(@PathVariable String id) {
    Integer siteId = Integer.parseInt(id);

    Site site = cms.getSite(siteId);
    SiteDTO siteResult = new SiteDTO(site);
    return siteResult;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/rest/sites", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public SitesResult getSites(@RequestParam Integer companyId) {
    Collection<Site> sites = cms.getSites(cms.getCompany(companyId));
    SitesResult sitesResult = new SitesResult(sites);
    return sitesResult;
}

}
```

(I skipped some code that doesn't apply to the problem)

When I go to the URL `/rest/sites/1` it is returning the data that I expect, but when I go to `/rest/sites?companyId=1` I get a 404 page: `HTTP Status 404 - /rest/rest/sites`.

The log is showing that the code in the `getSites`function is run, but after that the log is showing the following: `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView                     Forwarding to resource [rest/sites] in InternalResourceView 'rest/sites'`

Why is it redirected instead of executed?

**UPDATE**

Found the problem. Because I didn't have `@ResponseBody` above my method, the dispatcher forwarded my request. More information [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html), the key thing was `If the method is annotated with @ResponseBody, the return type is written to the response HTTP body. The return value will be converted to the declared method argument type using HttpMessageConverters.`

Comment: What kind of object is `SitesResult`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your method return type `SitesResult` is not one of the [supported return types](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html), Spring will add the returned object to the `Model` using its class name and try to render a view named by the value of your request mapping, which is why it is trying to render `/rest/sites`. It's not actually doing an HTTP forward, but a dispatcher forward which is what `servlets` do to render a view (eg. `jsp`).

If you want to return a specific view, return a String containing its name.

Instead

```
@RequestMapping(value="/rest/sites", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public SitesResult getSites(@RequestParam Integer companyId) {
    Collection<Site> sites = cms.getSites(cms.getCompany(companyId));
    SitesResult sitesResult = new SitesResult(sites);
    return sitesResult;
}
```

Do this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/rest/sites", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getSites(@RequestParam Integer companyId, Model model) {
    Collection<Site> sites = cms.getSites(cms.getCompany(companyId));
    SitesResult sitesResult = new SitesResult(sites);
    model.addAttribute("sitesResult", sitesResult);
    String myView = "myView";
    return myView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I found my problem and solution. You gave me an idea when you told about 'supported return types'. I missed `@ResponseBody` annotation above my method. This solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess on my part...

Method getSites could be declared as :

```
public SitesResult getSites(@RequestParam("companyId") Integer companyId) {
```

I don't know if this would have any effect?

Or could it be that the logical view name specified does not map to a view?